# Popup window not centering using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, popup

I am new to this, and tried several thing posted. I can get a popup window with my html page on the same domain, but can not center it. Here is my code:

JS:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<script>
jQuery.fn.center = function(){
   this.css("position", "fixed");
   this.css("top", ($(window).height() / 2) - (this.outerHeight() / 2));
   this.css("left", ($(window).width() / 2) - (this.outerWidth() / 2));
   return this;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a#Popup').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      window.open(
         $(this).attr("href"),
         "popupWindow",
         "width=760,height=720,scrollbars=no"
      );
   });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<td>
   <li>
      <a id="Popup" href="/images/Gallery/CustomBumperPlates/CustomBumperPlates.html" title="Gallery">
         Custom Bumper Plates
      </a>
   </li>
</td>
```

I have done it so many ways, not sure how to center it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that you're essentially trying to move around another window with jQuery after it loads, which you can't do the way you're trying. Do this instead:

```
$('a#Popup').click(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var width = 760;
    var height = 720;
    var toppx = ($(window).height() / 2) - (height / 2);
    var leftpx = ($(window).width() / 2) - (width / 2);
    window.open($(this).attr("href"), "popupWindow", "width=" + width + ",height=" + height + ",scrollbars=no,left=" + leftpx + "top="+toppx);
});
```

This sets the window left and right like you do in your center function, only it sets it on the window when it's opened.